# Google drive API ruby native application, how to retrieve the authorization code in terminal automatically

Tags: ruby, google-oauth

I am trying out the ruby tutorial from google developers and the are using

```
client.authorization.client_id = CLIENT_ID
client.authorization.client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
client.authorization.scope = OAUTH_SCOPE
client.authorization.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI
client.authorization.scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
uri = client.authorization.authorization_uri

$stdout.write uri
$stdout.write  "   "
# Exchange authorization code for access token
$stdout.write  "Enter authorization code: "
client.authorization.code = gets.chomp
client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
```

this way to show how to fetch the authorization code by opening the url in browser and then copying and pasting the given auth code in terminal. So, how do i do it automatically in terminal without needing to copy and paste the auth code?

Comment: If this is an oauth variant, you *cannot* fully automate the process - a key stage of oauth is that your app has to cede control to something hosted by Google that the end user interacts with. If you are automating a process for yourself, you could probably put something together to make it less painful from the command line. At least some part of the process must go via the browser (or possibly some other Google-hosted system that the user gets to interact directly with)

Comment: Oh, okay. so is there a way in ruby to open the url generated and then retrieve the code parameter from the redirected uri. now i can open the url using this same way but if i specify a redirect url on my localhost how do i request that auth code from my ruby app. or i should use some other third party authentication like omniauth and not do it manually at all

Comment: The usual route for a web app is to have some script on the redirect URL that you host, which then saves the auth code for your app to use. For a command-line application, I am not sure what your options are.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to open a url and then check if its closed or not in ruby?? so that i can open the url and then use a script to write the auth code to a file and then read the file when the browser url is closed

Comment: Best I could find was advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317987/authorizing-command-line-tool-to-consume-google-apis-through-oauth2-0-or-anythi

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i used a different workaround for time being. What i am doing is setting up a php script that writes the auth code to a file. and then giving that file's address as the redirect link and then in my ruby app i am using while File.zero?("document.txt")
 end which checks if file is empty or not. after my php scripts writes the code to this file, it is not empty so i retrieve the code and then empty it so that next time it reads it is already empty before getting the code