# Login with Google+ account programmatically

Tags: go, google-account

there is a service where one can authorize using their Google account.
I need to automate the workflow with that service, so my software has to log-in with a given Google account.
But as I've never done that before I don't know where to start. Most related answers suggest to display the authorization page to the user letting them to enter their login/password of their Google account, but that's not the case since my software must be fully automated, plus it is being ran in terminal mode so no browser neither any human to enter anything should be involved.

I wonder if such automation could be possible and where should I start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13317987/121660

Comment: That answer suggests making a simple web server to perform the [oauth flow](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth) until you get a refresh token. You can then give the refresh token to your command line app to exchange for a valid access token. Kind of a run around, but there it is.

Comment: @captncraig sorry but I don't think you're right here. Yes, the question is similar, but I don't find any answer other than running a webserver and ask the user to enter their password all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to authenticate a user with google is through a three-legged [oauth](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth) authentication flow (in a browser). You can do this in go using the [oauth2](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2) or with a more comprehensive package like [goth](https://github.com/markbates/goth)

The general flow is:

1. redirect user to a landing page on google's site where they are prompted to grant you access.
2. google will make a callback to your site with a special code.
3. you make another request to exchange that code for an access token and a refresh token.
4. Use access token to use google apis, and use refresh token to get a new access token anytime it expires.

It is more detailed than this, and there is a lot to get right to keep it secure, but that is the general idea.

Now, like you've said, your app is a command line thing, so it is hard to do that flow. Unfortunately, you may need to do that once, just to get a refresh token. Once you have that, you could give it to your application: `myapp -google-token=FOOBAR123`, and your app can exchange the referesh token for a valid access token.

Maybe this will help: https://github.com/burnash/gspread/wiki/How-to-get-OAuth-access-token-in-console%3F